# postgresql change clustername but pg_lsclusters say it not changed

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT current_setting('cluster_name'), current_setting('server_version');
```

return:

```
 current_setting |         current_setting
-----------------+----------------------------------
 my_cluster_14   | 14.3 (Ubuntu 14.3-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

My Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

But when I run **pg_lsclusters**
It return

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
14  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

which means
I can only do

```
sudo /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 14/main reload
```

I cannot do

```
/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 14/my_cluster_14 reload
```

I thought If I renamed the cluster name, I can do

```
/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 14/my_cluster_14 reload
```

So
is possible to run `/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 14/my_cluster_14 reload`?
What the use case of rename the cluster_name?  \

---

**solved** via
`sudo /usr/bin/pg_renamecluster 14 main  my_cluster_14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`pg_renamecluster`](https://manpages.org/pg_renamecluster) command:

> pg_renamecluster changes the name of a PostgreSQL cluster, i. e. the
> name of the config directory in /etc/postgresql/version/ along with
> the data directory in /var/lib/postgresql/version/. Existing log files
> in /var/log/postgresql/ are also renamed. The cluster is stopped and
> started for the operation.
>
> The following postgresql.conf config options are updated to refer to
> the changed path names: data_directory, hba_file, ident_file,
> external_pid_file, stats_temp_directory.
>
> Cluster names are a Debian convention, the name is not explicitly
> known to the cluster itself. From the PostgreSQL viewpoint, the name
> is merely a substring of various path names.